# Make [handlebars] a synonym of [handlebars.js]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[handlebars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/handlebars) (97 followers, 1,124 questions) should be a synonym of [handlebars.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/handlebars.js) (404 followers, 3,337 questions) because:

- The tags and their wiki both refer to the same framework
- When a question is only tagged [handlebars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/handlebars) it will receive less attention from the majority of those who could provide an answer
- A question could be tagged with both tags, making one of the two redundant

Comment: Actually, it would be better for a mod to simply merge them. Auto-completion works fine then.

Comment: I think a synonym is better, or else the tag will be re-introduced by others. [tag:ember] is a synonym of [tag:ember.js], [tag:angular] is a synonym of [tag:angularjs], [tag:knockout] is a synonym of [tag:knockout.js]...